# ModuleNotFoundError with pip after upgrading

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am working on a pip-installable program. This program has worked fine for months. Recently, I have upgraded python from 3.5 to 3.6, and also upgraded pip, and switched to a virtual environment. After I was done, my program no longer worked.

I used to install the program with

```
pip install --editable /path/myprogram
```

and call it with

```
myprogram --parameter "example parameter"
```

This used to work fine.

Now, I get an error when I run the second command:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myprogram.executable'

The folder structure of my program looks like this:

```
path
-setup.py
-myprogram
--__init__.py
--executable.py
--constants.txt
```

setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import find_packages
setup(
  name = 'myprogram',
  packages = find_packages(),
  version = '1.0',
  package_data={
      '': ['*.txt',
   },
   entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'myprogram=myprogram.executable:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

why does it suddenly no longer work?
Is it because of the versions of Python? Of pip? The Virtual Environment?

Comment: Have you checked your path? Maybe you're running the old version of myprogram? (or did you uninstall it globally first?)

Comment: I uninstalled it so that 'which myprogram' returns an empty list.